# Token names in ANLTR4

Tags: c#, regex, lexer, antlr4

I have the following lexer rules in AnTLR4

```
TRY: 'try';
FINALLY: 'finally';
EXCEPT: 'except';
IF: [i][f];
...
```

and the generated code in C# is:

```
public static readonly string[] tokenNames = { 
  "<INVALID>", "TRY", "'finally'", "'except'", "IF", ... }
```

My questions:

1. Why the rule name for the TRY token is `TRY` but the FINALLY token is named `'finally'`.
2. Also, I noticed that the first token after the `<INVALID>` is always named in uppercase
3. Any reason for the rulenames differ when we write `[i][f]` or `if`?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Literal token names are only used in very limited situations, where *all* of the following conditions are met:

1. The right-hand-side of the lexer rule contains exactly one string literal (nothing more, nothing less).
2. Exactly one rule in the grammar consists of that string literal. If two different rules in two different modes use the same string literal, then *neither* of them will appear with that string literal in the `tokenNames` array.

To answer your questions:

1. The `TRY` rule is either abbreviated in your question (i.e. your actual grammar contains a predicate or action for the rule), or another lexer rule somewhere in your grammar uses `'try'` on the right hand side.
2. The names are taken from the lexer rule names. If your rule was named `Try` instead of `TRY`, then it would appear as `Try` in the `tokenNames` array.
3. This rule does not consist of a string literal, so the `tokenNames` array uses the rule name instead of a literal.